# Ajax + servlet GET request issue

Tags: ajax, web-applications, servlets, xmlhttprequest, cors

I want to create a simple AJAX call, based on [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax) answer.
The servlet processes the request (it can print on console in the doGet() function), but nothing happens on the client side.
Chrome error message is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/package/servlet. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Thanks!

Comment: So the servlet runs on a different domain than the page sending the ajax request? Is this absolutely necessary?

Comment: I run the html from the local storage (C:). Is that a problem? How should I run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I run the html from the local storage (C:). Is that a problem? How should I run it?*

That is definitely a problem. You should request the HTML over HTTP instead. Your target endusers also won't run HTML from the local disk file system, right?

Open http://localhost:8080/package/filename.html in your browser.

Comment: Oh yeah, you were right! I'm running now the html on the same domain, and it works fine. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the browser side is rejecting the AJAX request/response based on [*Cross Origin Resource Sharing*](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).  That is where the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is coming from.  Give [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) a read for some hints on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen this thread before, but it didn't help.